# Dijkstra's method on matrix (java)

Tags: java, matrix, dijkstra

So our professor is requiring us to use an adjacency matrix for this implementation of Dijkstra.

After many a out of bounds exception, I'm at a bit of a loss of what to do here. I know Dijkstra can be done with 2D arrays, but I'm really having issues with it.

I can find out the out of bound exceptions here, but is there something fundamentally wrong I'm doing? Here's the code. Note that the input is wacky (the professor has a weird standard input), but for your sanity, type in:

```
3
2
7
1 2 50
3 1 20
3 2 60
5 1 40
3 4 30
4 2 20
0 4 8
```

if you want to test it. This will create a 6x6 array that links the points given in the 3-part input together by the ending number's weight.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class cmsc401 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        int intersections = read.nextInt();
        int friends = read.nextInt();
        int links = read.nextInt();
        int breakpoint = friends + 1;
        int total = friends + intersections + 1;
        int[][] matrix = new int[total][total];


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String next = "";
        int from = 0;
        int to = 0;
        int distance = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++){
                //matrix[x][y] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < links; x++){
            next = in.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(next);
            from = Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());
            to = Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());
            distance = Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());
            matrix[from][to] = distance;
            matrix[to][from] = distance;

    }

        for(int x = 1; x < breakpoint; x++){
            System.out.println(shortestRoute(x,0,matrix));
        }
    }

    public static boolean contains(int[] B, int a){
        for(int x = 0; x< B.length; x++){

            if (B[x] == a){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }


    public static int findShortest(int start, int[][] A, int[] visited, int[][] distances){
        int potential = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int potentialAddress = -1;
        for(int x = 0; x < A[start].length; x++){
            if(A[start][x] != 0 && contains(visited,x) == false){
                if(distances[x][1] < potential){
                    potential = A[start][x];
                    potentialAddress = x;
                }
            }
        }
        return potentialAddress;
    }

    public static int DistanceTo(int a, int b, int[][]A, int[][] distances){
        int potential = distances[a][1] + A[a][b];
        if(potential < distances[b][1]){
            return potential;
        }else{
            return distances[b][1];
        }
    }

    public static int backUp(int[] visited, int[][] distances){
        int potential = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int potentialAddress = -1;

        for(int x = 0; x < distances.length; x++){
            if(distances[x][1] < potential && contains(visited,x) == false){
                potentialAddress = x;
                potential = distances[x][1];
            }
        }

        return potentialAddress;
    }


    public static int shortestRoute(int start, int finish, int[][] A){
        int[] visited = new int[A.length];
        int numVisited = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < visited.length; x++){
            visited[x] = -1;
        }

        int[][] distances = new int[A.length][2];

        for(int x = 0; x < distances.length; x++){
            distances[x][0] = x;
            distances[x][1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        int current = start;
        int next = 0;
        while(numVisited < visited.length){
            if(numVisited == visited.length - 1){
                visited[numVisited] = current;
                continue;
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < A[current].length; x++){
                int position = A[current][x];
                if (position != 0 && contains(visited,x) == false){
                    distances[x][1] = DistanceTo(current,x,A,distances);
                }
            }

            if(findShortest(current,A,visited,distances) == -1){
                if(backUp(visited,distances) == -1){
                    break;
                }else{
                    backUp(visited,distances);
                }
            }
            visited[numVisited] = current;
            numVisited++;
            next = findShortest(current,A,visited,distances);
            current = next;
        }

        return distances[finish][1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which lines the index out of bounds exception occurs? Its a little easier to debug from there.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at cmsc401.shortestRoute(cmsc401.java:126)
 at cmsc401.main(cmsc401.java:50)

Comment: I updated the code to take out some test prints I was doing. Sorry about that.

Comment: please comment the code with the logic used